# Migrate Windows 7 from a dead PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, migration

I have an HDD from a dead PC I'm trying to use for new PC with a very different configuration, carrying over the OS. All MS solutions center around running something on the old PC first - "sysprep", "Easy Transfer", "Upgrade". Repairing OS doesn't do anything. What can I do to do the migration?

Here's what I get when I start it with "Disable automatic restart on system failure": https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CPFHFzkSipX6ezgMI8L1DfCj3FcuDsyj/view?usp=sharing
"Enable Boot Logging" doesn't create Ntbtlog.txt at all. Nothing gets created in Windows\Minidump\ either.
"Safe Mode" goes into BSOD after loading classpnp.sys: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v9-Oq5UYOy0H69wpSi_T6T5DEaqvCNWg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Assuming your new PC was a purchase (not home brew) then it came with Windows 10 and will not run Windows 7. If you can read the old hard drive in a carrier, recover your data and move on to Windows 10

Comment: Yep. Windows 7 is done. Your only option would be to try to virtualize it on top of a modern OS like Windows 10. Not many valid reasons for trying to keep Windows 7 which will literally be a dead, completely unsupported OS in a month.

Comment: New PC is built from parts I've selected without OS. A fresh install of Windows 7 runs without problems, but I need to restore the old one to avoid reinstalling everything. I may use Win 10 as a 2nd OS, but so far there's been no reason to. It's not gonna become my main OS for a very long time due to its forced V-Sync that kills framerate in some windowed mode games.

Comment: I would really recommend investing the time to move on to Windows 10 and reinstalling everything. I can think of no good reason to keep using Windows 7 and now is the perfect moment to get rid of it.

Comment: Are you are trying to boot on the new PC with the old disk? You might try from this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2673509/you-receive-error-stop-error-code-0x0000007b-inaccessible-boot-device) methods 1 and 3. If you don't have a recovery disk, use a boot media of the same service-pack level.

Comment: harrymc, tried them, didn't help. By comparing with a bootable OS I see that BSOD happens after all drivers are loaded and OS is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get started, I must issue a warning:
Windows 7 is not supported on newer hardware made after 2016-ish, and will be officially reaching end-of-life status in January, 2020 (just over a month from now).  If you're transferring the Win7 instance to new hardware, I would highly recommend restoring it to a VM rather than running it bare-metal.

Now, moving right along...

This is a long, complicated process, so 3rd-party software might be more beneficial here.  But the fully Microsoft-supported way to capture an OS instance is with DISM.  It's not strictly necessary to use `sysprep` first (it's highly recommended that you do, but not an option in your case).  All you have to do is attach the dead PC's hard drive to a working Windows PC (either to one of its SATA ports or via a USB dock) and issue the following command:

```
dism /capture-image /imagefile:"whatever.wim" /capturedir:E:\ /name:"Old HDD" /compress:max /verify /EA`
```

/Imagefile is the full path and name of the WIM file you want to create, enclosed in quotes (e.g. `"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Old Drive.wim"`).  /Capturedir is the letter and root path of the old hard drive you're capturing (e.g. `E:\` or `F:\`).  /Name can be whatever friendly name you want, enclosed in quotes.

Pay attention to the colons.  There should be no spaces between the colons and the parameter (so `/capturedir:E:\` is the correct syntax.

Once you have the image file in hand, you can copy it to a USB stick or whatever and transfer it to the new PC (or VM).

---

Boot the target PC/VM from any Windows ISO or USB stick, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> at the Windows Setup screen to bring up a command prompt.  You can then bring the image back down with another DISM command:

```
dism /apply-image /imagefile:"D:\whatever.wim" /applydir:C:\ /name:"Old HDD" /verify /EA
```

Same rules apply as the capture.  /Imagefile is the full path and name of the .WIM file you generated earlier (be sure to enclose it in quotes if the name has spaces in it!)  /ApplyDir is the letter and root path of the partition you're dumping it on.  /Name is the friendly name you gave it, enclosed in quotes.

**NOTE:**
Make sure your /applydir is a formatted, empty volume.  You definitely do not want to do this to a volume that already has data on it.  If the target drive is blank, you'll need to use `diskpart` to correctly create the required partitions.  How you do that depends on whether your drive is GPT or MBR, and whether your target is in UEFI or legacy BIOS mode.  All of that is a whole other topic beyond the scope of this question.  If you need help, you'll probably need to post it as another question.

---

Now that you've applied the image to the target volume, you'll need to make it bootable.  You can accomplish that with the `bcdboot` command:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s s: /l en-US /f ALL
```

`C:\Windows` needs to be the \Windows directory on whatever the current drive letter is for the volume you applied the image to.  It doesn't matter if it's not C:  It will be C: when Windows boots.

`/S` needs to be whatever volume Windows actually *boots* from, which is usually a hidden volume and **NOT** the C: drive!  You'll have to use `diskpart` to assign this volume a drive letter for the purposes of this command, since it usually does not get a drive letter at all.

---

You should be able to remove the ISO/USB stick at this point and reboot.  When Windows comes up, it will run a whole slew of hardware detections and some stuff may not work right.  Just be patient while it does all that.  Be sure you have drivers handy if you're doing this in a VM, install the VM add-ons program.  That will take care of all the drivers for you.